Irreducible tensor product representations in finite simple groups
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSp{PSp}\DeclareMathOperator\PSU{PSU}$Background:
A representation $ \rho: G \to \GL(V) $ of a group $ G $ on a (complex) vector space $ V $ is said to be irreducible if there are no nontrivial invariant subspaces under the action of $ G $. A tensor product of two irreducible representations $ \rho_i: G \to \GL(V_i) $, $i=1,2$, is a representation on the tensor product space $ V_1 \otimes V_2 $, defined by $ \rho_1(g) \otimes \rho_2(g) $ for $ g \in G $.
In some cases, this tensor product representation $ \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2 $ can itself be irreducible.
Examples:

If $V_1$ or $V_2$ is one-dimensional, then $ \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2 $ is irreducible.

Let $G$ be the product $ G_1 \times G_2 $. If $ \rho_i $ is an irreducible representation of $ G_i $, then the representation  $\rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2 = (\rho_1 \boxtimes 1) \otimes (1 \boxtimes \rho_2)$ is irreducible for $ G_1 \times G_2 $.


To avoid such straightforward examples, let us assume that $G$ is a non-abelian finite simple group and $\rho_i \neq 1 $. Surprisingly, such phenomenon is still possible in this case, but quite rare.
It occurs just on $10$ (among $204$) such groups of order less than $2.7\times 10^8$ (see the computations in Appendix), namely,
$$\PSp(4,3), \ M_{12}, \ A_9, \ \PSp(6,2), \ M_{23}, \ \PSU(5,2), \ 2F(4,2)', \ O_+(8,2), \ ^3D(4,2), \ M_{24}.$$
More specifically, for the alternating groups $A_n$,  with $5 \le n \le 21$, this phenomenon occurs just for $n=9,16$, with $(\dim(V_1),\dim(V_2))=(8,21), (15,12012)$, respectively.
For the sporadic groups, it occurs for $9$ ones (among $26$), namely,
$$M_{12}, \ M_{23}, \ M_{24}, \ Co_3, \ Co_2, \ Th, \ Co_1, \ F_{3+}, \ M.$$ Warning: This last list differs from (the complement of) the list in this review mentioned by Nick Gill in this comment.
Question: For which non-abelian finite simple groups this phenomenon occurs? more specifically, for which alternating groups $A_n$? if and only if $n$ is a square? and $\dim(V_1) = n-1$?
My laptop was not able to check up to $n=25$.

Computations
For general non-abelian finite simple groups (we know that we can avoid $\PSL(2,q)$, see here):
gap> simpnames:= AllCharacterTableNames( IsSimple, true, IsAbelian, false, IsDuplicateTable, false : OrderedBy:= Size);
gap> for nam in simpnames do if Size(nam)<3 or List([1..3],i->nam[i]) <> "L2(" then ct:=CharacterTable(nam); Print(nam," ",Size(ct)," ",c,"\n"); Phenomenon(ct); fi; od; 
...
U4(2), M12, A9, S6(2), M23, U5(2), 2F4(2)', O8+(2), 3D4(2), M24, ... the list should be incomplete after, because AllCharacterTableNames contains finitely many simple groups

For the alternating group $A_n$,  for $5 \le n \le 21$:
gap> for n in [5..21] do Print(n,"\n");; ct:=CharacterTable("Alternating", n); Phenomenon(ct);; od;
...
A9, A16

For the sporadic groups:
gap> spornames:= AllCharacterTableNames(IsSporadicSimple, true, IsDuplicateTable, false : OrderedBy:= Size);;
gap> for nam in spornames do ct:=CharacterTable(nam); Print(nam," ",Size(ct),"\n"); Phenomenon(ct); od;    
M12, M23, M24, Co3, Co2, Th, Co1, F3+, M

Script
LoadPackage("ctbllib"); LoadPackage("atlasrep");
Phenomenon:=function(ct)
    local irr,r,L,i,j,k;
    irr:=Irr(ct);
    r:=Size(irr);
    for i in [2..r] do
        for j in [i..r] do
            if IsIrreducible(irr[i]*irr[j]) then
                Print([i,j],"\n");; 
            fi;
        od;
    od;
end;;


Irreducible tensor products do exist for alternating group $A_n$ where $n$ is a square. Namely take $V_1$ to be representation of dimension $n-1$ (just as you suggested) and $V_2$ to be representation corresponding to square Young diagram of size $k\times k$ (since the diagram is invariant under transposition, the corresponding representation of the symmetric group splits into 2 non-isomorphic representations of the alternating group; choose any of them to be $V_2$). Then tensor product $V_1\otimes V_2$ is isomorphic to representation corresponding to the diagram $(k+1,k,\ldots,k,k-1)$.

Here is an example: for $k=5$ representation $V_1$ is of dimension 24 and representation $V_2$ is of dimension $350574510$ (I used wonderful Young Diagram Calculator https://www.integral-domain.org/lwilliams/Applets/Math/YoungDiagrams.php )

Magaard and Tiep have studied this problem in several papers. For instance, https://zbmath.org/0992.20009

The problem has been solved for the alternating groups by Bessenrodt and Kleshchev: https://zbmath.org/1009.20013

You get more examples if you work with quasimple groups instead of simple ones ( though the product characters might not be faithful, but contain (some of) the centre in their kernel. For example, the degree 4 irreducible characters of $A_{5}$ is a product of two characters of degree $2$ of ${\rm SL}(2,5).$

Notice that the groups ${\rm PSL}(2,5)$ and ${\rm PSL}(2,9)$ are two examples of simple groups which have irreducible characters that factorize when considered as characters of covering groups.

@NickGill: I recalculated for the sporadic groups (see my edits), and the results differ from those mentioned in the review you referred to in your first comment above.

@SebastienPalcoux, Can I check what, exactly, you are checking: do I understand that the 9 sporadic groups that you list are the ones with the property that there exist $U, V$  irreducible reps of dim $>1$ such that $U\otimes V$ is also irreducible? If so, then, yes, this seems inconsistent with the publication I link to. That publication only mentions the sporadic groups as an aside... and their example for $BM$, for instance, seems odd -- it refers to a rep which exists for $2BM$ but not for $BM$. So I am confused.

BTW, they summarise the Bessenrodt -- Kleschchev result as follows: if $\alpha, \beta$ are complex irreducible characters of degree $>1$ for an alternating group $A_n$ ($n\geq 5$), then $\alpha\otimes\beta$ is irreducible if and only if $n=a^2$ for some $a\geq 3$, one of the characters $\alpha, \beta$ is the nontrivial irreducible component of the natural permuation character, and the other one corresponds to the partition $(a^a)$.

@NickGill About your second last comment, the answer is yes.

This is not an answer, but it reminded me of a beautiful general argument of R. Brauer (which I first saw in a paper of David Wales, (credited to Brauer, though I am not sure whether Brauer ever published it in his own right)). This result may be marginally relevant to the question.
If we have an irreducible character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$ such that $\chi \overline{\chi} = 1 + \theta$ where $\theta$ is a (necessarily non-trivial and real-valued) irreducible character, then either $\theta$ is rational valued, or else there is a Galois conjugation $\sigma$ such that $\chi \chi^{\sigma}$ is irreducible.
For suppose that $\theta$ is not rational valued. Then there is a Galois conjugation $\sigma$ (commuting with complex conjugation) such that $\theta^{\sigma} \neq \theta.$
Then $\chi \chi^{\sigma} \overline{\chi \chi^{\sigma}} = 1 + \theta + \theta^{\sigma} + \theta \theta^{\sigma}.$
Since $\theta  = \overline{\theta}\neq \theta^{\sigma},$ the irreducible character $\theta^{\sigma}$ is different from $\overline{\theta}.$ Hence the trivial character only occurs once in $\chi \chi^{\sigma} \overline{\chi \chi^{\sigma}}$ and $\chi \chi^{\sigma}$ is irreducible.
Two examples where this occurs in practice are when $G ={\rm SL}(2,5)$ and $\chi$ is an irreducible character of degree $2$. Then $\chi \overline{\chi} = 1 +\theta,$ where $\theta$ is irreducible of degree three, but is not rational valued. Then $\chi \chi^{\sigma}$ is irreducible of degree $4$  where $\sigma$ is the Galois automorphism which squares odd order roots of unity and fixes $2$-power roots of unity. A similar example occurs for $G$ a triple cover of $A_{6}$, with $\chi$ irreducible of degree $3$ (with $\sigma$ cubing roots of unity of order prime to $3$ anf fixing roots of unity of $3$-power order).

There is an odd typo in the second line of the second paragraph. I'm guessing it ought to read "necessarily non-trivial irreducible character", but I'm not sure.

@DonuArapura : Yes, that was what I intended, thanks.

Also not an answer, just a hint on how the GAP code can be made a bit faster, for future reference: GAP actually "knows" the character tables for the alternating groups. For some reason I don't know this is not used here, but we can ask GAP directly for that character table, bypassing all computations in groups, to get a faster computation, like so:
LoadPackage("ctbllib");
Phenomenon:=function(n)
    local ct, irr,r,L,i,j,k;
    ct:=CharacterTable("Alternating", n);
    irr:=Irr(ct);
    r:=Size(irr);
    for i in [2..r] do
        for j in [i..r] do
            if IsIrreducible(irr[i]*irr[j]) then
                Print([i,j],"\n");; 
            fi;
        od;
    od;
end;;

for n in [5..20] do Print(n,"\n");; Phenomenon(n);; od;


Thanks! I expect your hint also applies to any finite simple groups of not too large an order.

Yes, the GAP packages atlasrep and ctbllib have character tables for the sporadic finite simple groups and several of the Lie types of not-too-big degree.

The BrowseAtlasInfo() function can be used to, well, browse a list of available tables. That can be helpful in finding out the right table for a group (e.g. the table for the O'Nan group is "ON")
